# What is the point of the lower camel case variable casing convention (thisVariable, for example)?

Tags: naming-conventions, camelcasing

I hope this doesn't get closed due to being too broad.  I know it comes down to personal preference, but there is an origin to all casing conventions and I would like to know where this one came from and a logical explanation as to why people use it.

It's where you go all like `var empName;`.  I call that lower camel, although it's probably technically called something else.  Personally, I go like `var EmpName`.  I call that proper camel and I like it.

When I first started programming, I began with the lower camel convention.  I didn't know why.  I just followed the examples set by all the old guys.  Variables and functions (VB) got lower camel while subs and properties got proper camel.  Then, after I finally acquired a firm grasp on programming itself, I became comfortable enough to question the tactics of my mentors.  It didn't make logical sense to me to use lower camel because it wasn't consistent, especially if you have a variable that consists of one word which ends up being in all lowercase.  There is also no validation mechanism in place to make sure you are appropriately using lower vs. upper camel, so I asked why not just use proper camel for everything.  It's consistent since all variable names are subject to proper camelization.

Having dug deeper into it, it turns out that this is a very sensitive issue to many programmers when it is brought to question.  They usually answer with, "Well, it's just personal preference" or "That's just how I learned it".  Upon prodding further, it usually invokes a sort of dogmatic reaction with the person as I attempt to find a logical reason behind their use of lower camel.

So anyone want to shed a little history and logic behind casing of the proper camelatory variety?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a combination of two things:

- The convention of variables starting with lower case, to differentiate from classes or other entities which use a capital. This is also sometimes used to differentiate based on access level (private/public)
- CamelCasing as a way to make multi-word names more readable without spaces (of course this is a preference over underscore, which some people use). I would guess the logic is that CamelCasing is easier/faster for some to type than word_underscores.

Whether or not it gets used is of course up to whomever is setting the coding standards that govern the code being written. Underscores vs CamelCase, lowercasevariables vs Uppercasevariables. CamelCase + lowercasevariable = camelCase

Answer (score 1):

In languages like C# or VB, the standard is to start private things with lowercase and start public/protected things with uppercase.  This way, just by looking at the first letter you can tell whether the thing you are messing could be used by other classes and thus any changes need more scrutiny.  Also, there *are* tools to enforce naming conventions like this.  The one created/used internally at Microsoft is called StyleCop and is available as a free download.

Comment: Should have called it styleCop, might have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, well named variables in C (a case-sensitive language) consisted of a single word in lower case. UPPERCASE was reserved for macros.

Then came along C++, where classes are usually CapitalizedAndCamelCased, and variables/functions consisting of several words are camelCased. (Note that C people tend to dislike camelCase, and instead write identifiers_this_way.

From there, it spread.

And, yes, probably other case-sensitive languages have had some influence.

Comment: I think the wimpyCaps fad is much more prevalent in Java and JavaScript code than it is in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

lowerCamelCase I think has become popular because of java and javascript.
In java, it is specifically defined why, that the first word should be a verb with small letters where the remaining words start with a capital letter.

The reason why java chose lowerCamelCase I think depends on what they wanted to solve. Java was launched in 1995 as a language that would make programming easy. C/C++ that was often used was often considered difficult and too technical.
This was something java claimed to solve, more people would be able to program and the same code would work on different hardware. The code was the documentation, you didn't need to comment code, just read and everything would be great.

lowerCamelCase makes it harder to write "technical" code because it removes options to use uppercase and lowercase letters to better describe the code from a technical perspective. Java didn't want to be hard, java was the language to use where everyone could learn to program.

javascript in browsers was created in 10 days by Brendan Eich in 1995. Why javascript selected lowerCamelCase I think is because of java. It has nothing to do with java but it has "java" in its name "javascript".